# String handling and encoding between Java and Oracle

Tags: java, string, oracle, encoding, oracle11g

I have some code that does something like this:

```
String incomingContent = getContent();

if (incomingContent.length() > 14){
 return incomingContent.substring(0,14);
}
```

`GetContent()` returns a string with the text `"Lorem Ipsum § Lorem ipsum"`

The returned truncated string is saved into an Oracle database but Oracle complains that the string is greater than the column size. The column size is defined as `VARCHAR2(14 BYTE)`.

Any ideas why this is happening? I suspect that it is the `§` character in the string but im not sure.  I know that the Oracle database only supports UTF-8. Could this be the reason for this incorrect size/length of the string?

Why does Java say it is 14 characters but Oracle thinks it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the data type in Oracle is set to `BYTE` alignment instead of `CHAR` alignment you end up with any multi-byte characters eating up multiple "slots" out of the available 14. For example, `VARCHAR2(2 BYTE)` will hold two 1-byte characters or only one 2-byte character (and won't hold a 3-byte character at all). In Java, however, `substring()` will count even 2-byte characters as a single character so you end up sending too much data for the Oracle column to hold.

You can use `VARCAHR2(14 CHAR)` in oracle (which will hold 14 multi-byte characters) and make your Java programming easy, or you can come up with an algorithm in Java that counts the number of bytes used by a string and then trim accordingly (making sure not to cut multi-byte characters in the middle).

Comment: Ok got it. Looks like ill have to truncate them in bytes as i cant change the column type.